# How to say « peut-on ne pas rêver »?

Tags: grammar, translation

I want to say this french sentence, in English. I hesitate between

> Can we not dream?
>   Can we don’t dream?
>   Can’t we dream?

I want to ask for is it possible to not dream?

Comment: "Can we not dream?" is a more emphatic reordering of "Cannot we dream?" The second is off. "Can't we dream?" loses something of the original.

Comment: Loosely, but at least natural in English and with some life: We can still dream, can't we?

Comment: Welcome et bienvenue to ELU.  Can you clarify the context of dreaming?

Comment: Off topic because it's a translation request or off topic because it's a proofreading request? Either way, how many users are going to want to translate « peut-on ne pas rêver » into English? This might be an interesting question, but it's not a useful question (to other people).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a translation request.

Answer (score 3):

I think you said it yourself: "Is it possible to not dream?"

It seems you're talking about literal dreaming (that thing that happens when you sleep) as opposed to "grand imagining" and while "Can we not dream" is correct, out of context it implies "grand imagining" not sleep-dreams.  "Is it possible to not dream?" suffers less from that ambiguity.

Comment: The word order here is odd. *Not* usually comes before the complete infinitive ("Is it possible not to dream?"); but that has a subtly different meaning from "Is it not possible to dream?" And, I think, the question is actually asking about the "grand imagining" use of *dream* (although that's not entirely clear).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: the word order is just a split infinitive. It's not that odd, although some people would argue that it's better to not split infinitives.

Comment: @PeterShor Well, of course, idiolects are never awkward to the people who use them.

Answer (score 0):

When one says *peut-on ne pas rêver?*, it is often an exhortation to be serious. An idiomatic way to say this in English is **Can we stop dreaming?** or **Would you stop dreaming?**.

Regarding your choices, **Can we not dream?** is a precise translation of *Peut-on ne pas rêver ?*. Your second choice is not grammatically correct. Your third choice, “Can’t we dream?”, translates *Ne peut-on pas rêver ?*, although a better translation would be “Dare we dream?” or even “Dare we not dream?”.

If you mean this as a rhetorical question, as in *Vous demandez que nos élus soient tous intègres. Peut-on ne pas rêver?*, it would be helpful if you could amend your question. There are idioms that express this sentiment better than a strict translation, for example *dream on!*, or *keep your feet on the ground*.

Comment: But in English, *Can we not dream* and *can't we dream* usually mean the same thing; the first is just a more formal and slightly archaic word oder. (In spoken English, *can we not dream* might mean *peut-on ne pas rêver?* depending on the emphasis; in written English, I think it would usually be taken to mean *ne peut-on pas rêver?*)

Comment: I hear you, although I wouldn't say archaic so much as declamatory. To my ear *can we not dream?* is an exhortation, that a minister or a politician might use when haranguing the public, while *can't we dream?* is a wish, maybe a little bit forlorn. I've just tried to see the difference in the mirror, and (as Peter Capaldi would say) basically it's the eyebrows.